# Enumerate by letters the list of size bigger than the list of letters

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I have an `enumerate` with lot of items (more then letters) which I want to enumerate by letters (not necessarily single letter labels), that is when single-letter-labels run out I want to have (aa), (ab) and so on.

> How can one do this?

Comment: Take a look at the `alphalph` package and its macro `\alphalph`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small example utilizing the `enumitem` package along with the `alphalph` package.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newcommand*\zz{\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz}
\newcommand*\zzz{\item foo\item bar\item baz}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\protect\alphalph{\value*})]
    \zz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]